# node http proxy port number to accept SSL traffic

Tags: node.js, ssl, proxy, node-http-proxy

Following example is taken from the github page of [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#upgrading-from-08x-)

```
HTTPS -> HTTP

//
// Create the HTTPS proxy server in front of a HTTP server
//
httpProxy.createServer({
  target: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9009
  },
  ssl: {
    key: fs.readFileSync('valid-ssl-key.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('valid-ssl-cert.pem', 'utf8')
  }
}).listen(8009);
```

Question: Why is httpProxy not listening to port 443 for secure SSL traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL has default port which is 443 but like with regular HTTP protocol which also has default 80 port it could be bind to a custom port and accessed by specifying a port in the url(https://localhost:8009). Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/791218/can-i-use-another-port-other-than-443-for-ssl-communication).

Comment: I see, but it would result in unnecessarily complicated urls like https://www.example.com:8009/foobar.html

Comment: Right, in most cases, using 443 port is more than enough but sometimes, for example when you hosting multiple sites on one server you should handle port conflicts and as a result, use a custom port for SSL.